# rsyslog - imfile-state configuration meanings

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

In a rsyslog directory for a service I am working with, there are a number of imfile-state files (for example, `imfile-state:163613:604cabbcd415ea81`). As far as I am aware, Rsyslog must keep track of which parts of the monitored file are already processed. This is done in so-called "state files". In these files, the following info can be found:

```
{ "filename": "\/path\/to\/file.log", "prev_was_nl": 0, "curr_offs": 17929530, "strt_offs": 17929530 }
```

I am unsure on what the following mean:

- prev_was_nl
- curr_offs
- strt_offs

I can't seem to find anything about them online - can anyone shed some light for me?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, to keep track of which parts of the monitored file are already processed, rsyslog uses the so-called “state files” that are created in the rsyslog working directory - `global(workDirectory)` - and are read on startup to resume monitoring after a shutdown.

According to the [rsyslog documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html#state-files), there is **intentionally** no more precise description of the state file *naming*, as this is an implementation detail and may change as needed.

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/master/plugins/imfile/imfile.c) of the `imfile` module, doesn't give much more information either.

So to now answer the question; *I don't know*. If you really want to know, you will probably have to ask a developer.